# Normalizing Feature/Label with Negative Values

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, data-transformation, tensorflow

I am creating a neural network using tensorflow that predicts the energy consumption of a vehicle. Originally, I planned on normalizing all of the features from 0 to 1 using the scikit-learn object MinMaxScaler. However, one of the features, altitude change, contains both positive and negative values. In addition, the label, energy consumption, can be negative due to the energy returned to the battery from regenerative braking. I need my model to respond differently to these negative values as opposed to the meaningless negative values of other features like temperature.

Is it best practice to instead normalize some/all features from -1 to 1? Or should I be standardizing all the features instead (even if they may not be normally distributed)?

Comment: My guess is that it does not matter much, there can always be negative weights (or negative biases in you use ReLU inside the net) that should be able to get things right. As always in machine learning, try everything and see what works best.

Comment: Appreciate the response, still quite new to this. Won't negative values be outputted as 0 through ReLU?

Comment: You can have negative weights, so different neurons can respond to positive values and different to negative values, but it does not mean negative values get forever.

Comment: I disagree with above comment, I think what you need to adjust really depends on your specific task. If you try to express degrees in negative values of certain features then using relu is a poor choice because all negative values, regardless of degree, will be converted to zero via relu. In certain models I normalized to (-1;1) and use tanh which can capture the negative values of the normalization. With relu, from my experience it makes much more sense to normalize to (0; some positive value)